# Rails update_attributes if value is present, else nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

On Rails 5.

I have a `Service` model with `access_token` and `expires_at` attributes.

I am making an API request to fetch the access token and expiration, however, in many cases the expires_at is not present, in which case I would like the value to be nil.

In my controller, I am doing something basic like:

```
@service.update_attributes(
    access_token: api_response["access_token"],
    expires_at: Time.at(api_response["credentials"]["expires_at"])
  )
```

What is the correct way to only update `expires_at` if the api response contains it?

I was thinking of setting a variable if present:

```
if api_response["credentials"]["access_token"].present?
  expiry = api_response["credentials"]["access_token"]
else
  expiry = nil
end
```

then updating like...

```
@service.update_attributes(expires_at: expiry)
```

But this doesn't seem like the correct way to do it. And if I need to check multiple values from the api response, there would be a lot of extra code just to check presence.

What would be the Rails way to do this? Having a hard time finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're on the right track here:

```rb
    @service.access_token = api_response["access_token"]
    @service.expires_at = Time.at(api_response["credentials"]["expires_at"]) if api_response["credentials"]["expires_at"].present?
    @service.save if @service.changed?
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Time.at() is expecting a valid value, which is why I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something more general if you want to check other values as well.

```rb
def check_and_return(api, value = "access_token")
  api[value].present? ? expiry = Time.at(api[value]) : expiry = nil
  return expiry
end
expiry = check_and_return(api_response["credentials"])
@service.update_attributes(expires_at: expiry)
```

With this, you can also pass other values, for instance:

```rb
check_and_return(api_response["other_credentials"], "other_token")
```